# React functional components props value not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to simply render the `props.item` 's value based on parent state but it is always showing the initial value. However, inside useEffect the `props.item` has the updated value. How can I make use of the updated props values without saving it into state ? In Component based classes this would of worked without state.

//EDIT:

Parent:

```
function App() {
  const [activePageIndex, setActivePageIndex] = useState(0);
  const changeActivePageIndex = (index) => {    setActivePageIndex(index);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="app-content">
        <Carousel
          activePageIndex={activePageIndex}
          onScroll={changeActivePageIndex}
        />
      </div>
   </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Child:

```
const Carousel = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
//Here it shows the updated value

  }, [props.activePageIndex]);
//Here it shows the OUTdated value
  return <div className="carousel-container">{props.activePageIndex}</div>;
};

export default Carousel;
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that has this problem?

Comment: @NicholasTower you are right. I added it just now

Answer (score 1):

could you please add a lil more, it does not cost any money if you add some:

- code snippets.
- expected behavior.
- actual behavior.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
const Carousel = ({activePageIndex}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
//Here it shows the updated value

  }, [activePageIndex]);
//Here it shows the updated value
  return <div className="carousel-container">{activePageIndex}</div>;
};

export default Carousel;
```

Answer (score 0):

try passing the `setActivePageIndex` directly as props.

Ex-

```
function App() {
  const [activePageIndex, setActivePageIndex] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="app-content">
        <Carousel
          activePageIndex={activePageIndex}
          onScroll={(e) => setActivePageIndex(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
   </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```