# Why to use Object.assign() to update functional component props change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

I have a list of students and I display them on the table. There are two buttons that indicate by which value should I sort the list (name or birthdate). When the button is clicked and I sort the list, the list itself is getting sorted, but it's not updating if I don't assign the list to the new list using `Object.assign(newList, oldList)` and then update it by passing to the update state function `updateList(newList)`. Here's my code:

```
const students= [
  {
    name: "John Done",
    year: 1,
    birthdate: "2020-01-24",
  },
  {
    name: "Another Done",
    year: 3,
    birthdate: "2002-02-20",
  },
  {
    name: "Jack London",
    year: 2,
    birthdate: "1800-01-04",
  },
  {
    name: "Text Name",
    year: 3,
    birthdate: "1990-02-24",
  },
  {
    name: "Name",
    year: 2,
    birthdate: "2005-04-01",
  },
];

ReactDOM.render(<App students={students} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

```
function App({ students }) {
  const [studentsList, setStudentsList] = useState(students);

  const sortByYear = () => {
    // let sortedstudents = [];
    // Object.assign(sortedStudents, studentsList);
    // sorteStudents.sort((a, b) => b.year - a.year);
    // console.log(sorteStudents);
    // setStudentsList(sortedStudents);
    studentsList.sort((a,b) => b.year - a.year));
    setStudentsList(studentsList);
  };

const sortByDates = () => {
  // let sortedStudents = [];
  // Object.assign(sortedStudents, studentsList);
  // sortedStudents.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.birthdate) - new Date(a.birthdate));
  // console.log(sortedStudents);
  // setStudentsList(sortedStudents);
  studentsList.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.birthdate) - new Date(a.birthdate));
  setStudentsList(studentsList);
};

return (
<div className="App">
  <div>
    <label>
      Sort By
    </label>
    <button
      onClick={() => sortByYear()}
    >
      Year
    </button>
    <button
      onClick={() => sortByDates()}
    >
      Most Old
    </button>
  </div>
  <Students students={studentsList} />
</div>
 );
}
```

---

### Students component

```
function Students({ students }) {
return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Date of birth</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {students.map((student, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{student.name}</td>
              <td>{student.year.toString()}</td>
              <td>{student.birthdate}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So here in this way even though the students' list is getting sorted, the state is not updating, but if I assign the initial list to the new one and then sort it and then update the state it is working.

### WORKS

```
let sortedStudents = [];
Object.assign(sortedStudents, studentsList);
sortedStudents.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.birthdate) - new Date(a.birthdate));
//console.log(sortedStudents);
setStudentsList(sortedStudents)
```

### DOES NOT WORK

```
studentsList.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.birthdate) - new Date(a.birthdate));
setStudentsList(studentsList);
```

So the question is why do I need to assign my `studentsList` to the new array, specifically by using `Object.assign()` so that `setStudentsList()` would update the component's state? I've just started learning React so it's really confusing me the way how these states actually work.

Similar posts I've found

- [React Functional Component props does not update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64849867/react-functional-component-props-does-not-update)
- [React functional components props value not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62052794/react-functional-components-props-value-not-updating)
- [Re render functional component on props change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240178/re-render-functional-component-on-props-change)
- [React: Passing down props to functional components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39963565/react-passing-down-props-to-functional-components?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: React determines if it should re-render or not based on the equality of previous props to the next props, and previous state to the next state. By mutating the original state array, the previous `studentList` has referential equality with the updated `studentList` and react will not detect that it needs to rerender.

Comment: `sort` mutates state and `assign` does not.

Comment: @BrianThompson Now it totally makes sense... Your comment answers my question. Please, let me know if I could improve my code because I'm not aware of best practices yet.

Comment: You don't want `Object.assign` here. You want `const sortedStudents = studentsList.slice();` (or any [alternative that copies the array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7486085/1048572)).

Comment: @Miraziz lol wouldn't call it "best practices" as much as "design limitations". I'm sure the React team would *love* to have the shorter version "just work" if they could do so reliably and with good performance :P

Comment: @JaredSmith haha, yes I'm just learning React and I'd like to if I'm understanding and learning concepts correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Brain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9381601/brian-thompson) mentioned:
React determines if it should re-render or not based on the equality of previous props to the next props, and previous state to the next state. By mutating the original state array, the previous studentList has referential equality with the updated studentList and react will not detect that it needs to rerender.

So in order to change the list and to React detect the changes, the *value* of the array needs to be used (mutated), instead of its *reference*.

As [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) hinted: [alternative that copies the array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value)